# Add Google login to OpenIddict Authorization Server - who provides the client_id and how?

Tags: openid-connect, openiddict

Starting with the [Zirku Sample](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Zirku) of OpenIddict, I wanted to add Google Accounts as login provider (nuget: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google`).

My changes include adding the google auth provider after `AddOpenIddict(...)`:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
        {
            options.CallbackPath = "/signin-google";
            options.ClientId = "0000000000000-redacted.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            options.ClientSecret = "redacted";
            options.SignInScheme = OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });
```

Adding `/signin-google` as valid authorization endpoint to allow calling SignIn:

```
options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize", "/signin-google")
       .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
       .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("/connect/introspect")
       .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo");
```

However, when coming back from google, the OpenIddict Server always complans, that the client_id is missing:

`fail: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0] The authorization request was rejected because the mandatory 'client_id' parameter was missing.`

Tried these config options already without any change:

```
options.AcceptAnonymousClients();
options.Configure(op => op.AcceptAnonymousClients = true);
```

What am I doing wrong?

complete log can be found [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bfJ6nSdGph/).

(and yes, I changed the port to 6001 to reuse an existing redirect-url registered at google)

Comment: Marc(https://stackoverflow.com/users/164162/marc-wittke) ,  did you manage to resolve your problem.  I am doing a POC with OpenIddict (username/password + Google Login) and cannot find a sample project to start from.

Comment: no, I abandoned the prototype, and we opted for another container in our k8s enironment based on keycloak. It is a bit heavyweight, but we did not regret it

Answer (score 0):

`options.AcceptAnonymousClients()` has no effect on the code flow as `client_id` is a mandatory parameter in this case (it only affects the token, introspection and revocation endpoints).

`options.SignInScheme` cannot be set to a scheme belonging to OpenIddict. In most cases, it must correspond to a cookie handler (typically the one registered by Identity).

You will also want to remove `/signin-google` from the endpoints managed by OpenIddict, as it will prevent the Google authentication handler from working properly.